# Python pd.read_sql dataframe KeyError

Tags: python, sql

I have a sql query to pull in contact records. I am looping through each record and assigning the values to variables in python.  It's working for all the values variible pairs except HMid. I can't for the life of me figure out why. When I print Updatedata HMid shows up fine as a number like this '106594451'.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
    updateSQL = """ Select c.mobilephone
        ,l.HMid         
        ,[firstname]
        ,[lastname]
        ,fullname
        ,[emailaddress1]     
    from contact c where and \ksl_communityid = '%s'
    

                        """  % (CommunityID)        
  
Updatedata = pd.read_sql(updateSQL, cnxnCS1)
print(Updatedata)


for i in range(len(Updatedata)):
    mobilephone = data.loc[i,'mobilephone']
    firstname = data.loc[i,'firstname']
    lastname = data.loc[i,'lastname']
    fullname = data.loc[i,'fullname']
    emailaddress1 = data.loc[i,'emailaddress1']
    HMid= data.loc[i,'HMid']
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'HMid'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-143-13351626f5cd> in <module>
     53     fullname = data.loc[i,'fullname']
     54     emailaddress1 = data.loc[i,'emailaddress1']
---> 55     HMid = data.loc[i,'HMid']
     56 
     57     print(HMid)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
__getitem__(self, key)    1759                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):    1760                     pass
-> 1761             return self._getitem_tuple(key)    1762         else:    1763             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
_getitem_tuple(self, tup)    1269     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):    1270         try:
-> 1271             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)    1272         except IndexingError:    1273             pass

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
_getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)    1418                     return section    1419                 # This is an elided recursive call to iloc/loc/etc'
-> 1420                 return getattr(section, self.name)[new_key]    1421     1422         raise IndexingError("not applicable")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
__getitem__(self, key)    1765     1766             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1767             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)    1768     1769     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
_getitem_axis(self, key, axis)    1962         # fall thru to straight lookup    1963         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1964         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)    1965     1966 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
_get_label(self, label, axis)
    618             # but will fail when the index is not present
    619             # see GH5667
--> 620             return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    621         elif isinstance(label, tuple) and isinstance(label[axis], slice):
    622             raise IndexingError("no slices here, handle elsewhere")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)    3535             loc, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key, drop_level=drop_level)    3536         else:
-> 3537             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)    3538     3539             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)  2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'HMid'
```

Comment: `KeyError` indicates that the column does not exist in the DataFrame.
List out all the columns you have with `print(data.columns)`

Comment: @thekenobe, That's what I thought but below is what I get.  It is listing HMid as a column but I am still getting the same key error.

Index(['mobilephone', 'HMid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'fullname',
       'emailaddress1'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Strange. You can debug further by wrapping in a `try-except`: 
```python
for i in range(len(Updatedata)):
    mobilephone = data.loc[i,'mobilephone']
    firstname = data.loc[i,'firstname']
    lastname = data.loc[i,'lastname']
    fullname = data.loc[i,'fullname']
    emailaddress1 = data.loc[i,'emailaddress1']
    try:
        HMid= data.loc[i,'HMid']
    except KeyError as e:
        print('i: {}, columns: {}'.format(i, data.loc[i].columns.tolist())
        raise e
```

Comment: I figured it out. I had changed the name of my df to try to solve a different issue I was having but didn't update each of the variable assignments, so it was populating those from the old df but didn't have the HMid column.     Thanks for you help it got me there eventually